# Does sequel sphere really work?

Tags: sql, html, local-storage, local

Just found Sequel Sphere and it is looking promising as a ay to store and query data fromHTML5 local storage, the SQL way.

But when I want to download the trial, there is a message:

*Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.*

Hence the question: does anybody use it successfully?

Comment: I get the same message and I have no solution. Have you tried [contacting them](https://www.sequelsphere.com/contact-us/)?

Comment: Just sent them a mail...